# Linux `top` command: how much process memory is physically stored in swap space?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, top-command, swapfile, memory-overcommitment

Let's say I run my program on a 64-bit Linux machine with 64 Gb of RAM. In my very small C program immediately after the start I do

```
void *p = sbrk(1024ull * 1024 * 1024 * 120);
```

this moving my data segment break forward by 120 Gb.

After the above `sbrk` call `top` entry for my process shows `RES` at some low value, `VIRT` at `120g`, and `SWAP` at `120g`.

After this operation I write something into the first 90 Gb of the above region

```
memset(p, 0xAB, 1024ull * 1024 * 1024 * 90);
```

This causes some changes in the `top` entry for my process: `VIRT` expectedly remains at `120g`, `RES` becomes almost `64g`, `SWAP` drops to around `56g`.

The common `Swap` stats in the header of `top` output show that swap file usage increases, which is expected since my program will have to push about 26 Gb of memory pages into the swap file.

So, according to the above observations, `SWAP` column simply reports my process's non-`RES` address space regardless of whether this address space has been "materialized", i.e. regardless of whether I already wrote something into that region of virtual memory.

But is there any way to figure out how much of that `SWAP` size has actually been "materialized" and backed up by something stored in the swap file? I.e. is there any way to make `top` to display that 26 Gb value for my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on a version of procps you are using. For instance, in version 3.0.5 SWAP value equals:

```
task->size - task->resident
```

and it is exactly what you are encountering. Man top.1 says:

```
VIRT = SWAP + RES
```

Procps-ng, however, reads /proc/pid/status and sets SWAP correctly

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/readproc.c#L383

So, you can update procps or look at /proc/pid/status directly